# angular reactive form wrong patchValue of arrayGroup

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have following problem, I want patchValue to angular reactive form
I use following code:

```
export function clearArray(formArray: FormArray) {
  while (formArray.controls.length) {
    removeAtIndex(formArray, 0);
  }
}

export function makeArrayForm(
  formArray: FormArray,
  modelGroup: AbstractControl,
  data: any[] = []
) {
  clearArray(formArray);
  let index = 0;
  do {
    formArray.push(modelGroup);
    index++;
  } while (index < data.length);
}

export function bindData(
  formArray: FormArray,
  modelGroup: AbstractControl,
  data: any[] = []
) {
  makeArrayForm(formArray, modelGroup, data);
  formArray.patchValue(data);
}
```

Model group is make by FormBuilder in conmponent where I call this function
I try add following array

```
[
    {{id:1, name:{Jonny}},
    {{id:2, name:{Tonny}}
]
```

After call bindData  value my form array is filled by last element of my array what Is wrong.
Where I made mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I solved It. the problem is that model group is object.
Object is passed via reference to function, so modelGroup is duplicated multitimes.
Solution

```
export function makeArrayForm(
  formArray: FormArray,
  formCreatorFunction: (FormBuilder) => FormGroup,
  formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  dateArray: any[] = []
) {
  clearArray(formArray);
  dateArray.forEach(() => {
    const newForm = formCreatorFunction(formBuilder);
    formArray.push(newForm);
  });
}
```